# What is difference between control.select() and selecting control by mouse left click?

Tags: c#, datagridview

I know i can select control using `control.Select();` and also select control using mouse left click on control.
But what i don't understand is when i select `DataGridView` using `datagridview.Select();` i can't use any event of `DataGridView` but when i select `DataGridView` by mouse left click i can use event of `DataGridView`.

I tried `control.Focus();`  and `ActiveControl` but it is also not responding to event.
What is missing?

Comment: It depends what type of events you want to call

Comment: my event is KeyUp event for datagridview.

Answer (score 0):

To call events programaticaly , use the code like this:

```
YourMethodName(TheControlName, null);
```

For example in this case, you should use:

```
datagridview_KeyUp( datagridview, null); //or whatever the name of your method and control, just replace it
```

Comment: Thanks for answer but i don't understand your answer.

Comment: Can you show the code which executes on your mouse click, but doesn't programaticaly

Comment: I think code is not problem at all but when i select datagridview by mouse while runtime using left click then keyup event code is executes but when i select gridview using select() i.e programmatically then datagridview is getting selected but it doesn't execute keyup event.